# FullCalendar PHP and MySQL integration, events don't update

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

So I was doing my regular browsing, when I saw FullCalendar, for the ones who don't know it, it's a drag and drop jQuery calendar.

Now, I want to make it work with my database using AJAX, but it wont really work..

Here's the JS for updating an event (changing dates etc)
 eventDrop: function(event, delta) {

```
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd");
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://127.0.0.1/public/assets/scripts/update_event.php',
         data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&user=' + '<?php echo $_SESSION['
         id '];?>',
         type: "POST",
         success: function(json) {
             alert("Updated Successfully");
         }
     });
 }
```

So this piece of JS's sees if a event is moved or anything and posts the new details to the following PHP scriptt:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/bootstrap.php');
global $conn;
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE title = :name AND start = :start');
$query->execute(array(':name' => $title, ':start' => $start));
while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $ids = explode(',', $result['user']);
    if (in_array($user, $ids))
    {
        $update = $conn->prepare('UPDATE calendar SET title = :title, start = :start, end = :end');
        $update->execute(array(':title' => $title, ':start' => $start,':end' => $end));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Since I'm using this in a user based envoriment, I needed to integrate something that'll work with userID's.

The DB connection is in the `bootstrap.php` file, which is being included at the top.

How is it possible that I get the 'updated successfully' alert, but my database isn't being updated?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're checking to see the `execute()` return value - if it is false then `errorInfo()` will give you the reason for failure. Don't forget that the `success` JavaScript callback is for the HTTP operation, not the database operation (so a failed database call can happen in a successful HTTP call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that wrong or missing parameters are being sent to the database.  Output all your necessary parameters in the alert Eg.

```
alert("Updated Successfully. title=" + event.title);
```

And see if anything is blank.  Also, just looking at your code I don't see where "name" is coming from.  That may be your problem resulting in a malformed SELECT query.